# Non-blocking websockets client using AIOHTTP

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, aiohttp

I'm trying to build a websocket live-chat client on Python using websockets from AIOHTTP.
I'm having issues with `msg = await ainput('> ')` - this is blocking code. After i run this code, client blocked on this line until user enter some value. After value is entered displays one message from server and blocked on this line again.

```
async def client_run():

    async with ClientSession().ws_connect('http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws') as ws:

        await ws.send_str('Hello!')
        async for msg in ws:
            if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
                if msg.data == 'close cmd':
                    await ws.close()
                    break
                else:
                    await aprint('Message received from server:', msg)
                    msg = await ainput('> ')
                    await ws.send_str(msg)
            elif msg.type == WSMsgType.ERROR:
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Type "exit" to quit')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(client_run())
```

I tried to rewrite this code as two separate tasks, but I ran into a context manager problem. And client still blocked.

```
async def run_client(ws):
    await ws.send_str('Hello!')
    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
            if msg.data == 'close cmd':
                await ws.close()
                break
            else:
                await aprint('Message received from server:', msg)

async def promt(ws):
    while True:
        msg = await ainput('Your text here: ')
        await ws.send_str(msg)


async def main():
    async with ClientSession().ws_connect('http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws') as ws:
        await asyncio.gather(
            run_client(ws),
            promt(ws)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Type "exit" to quit')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

What is the solution for non-blocking live-chat client?

Answer (score 2):

For non-blocking client need to create separate tasks for read and write.
This works fine.

```
async def run(ws):
    async for msg in ws:
        if msg.type == WSMsgType.TEXT:
            print('Message received from server:', msg)


async def promt(ws):
    while True:
        msg = await ainput('> ')
        await ws.send_str(msg)


async def main():

    async with ClientSession().ws_connect('http://0.0.0.0:8080/ws') as ws:
        run_task = asyncio.create_task(run(ws))
        promt_task = asyncio.create_task(promt(ws))
        await asyncio.gather(promt_task, run_task)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Type "exit" to quit')
    asyncio.run(main())
```